# Issue compiling C++ code in R using TMB package

Tags: c++, r, tmb

I am trying to apply a hierarchical compensation model written in C++ that was developed by a colleague some years back. I am trying to use the TMB package to compile the code and then apply the model to some education data I have pulled from the BLS and an internal database.

However when I used the compile function in TMB I get the following while running in R version 3.6.0

```
Error in compile("hierarchical_earnings_model.cpp") : Compilation failed
```

I tried using the debug function with compile to see what is occurring to cause this error- but I am afraid my R knowledge is too low to understand the debug results.

```
debug(compile('hierarchical_earnings_model.cpp'))
debugging in: compile("hierarchical_earnings_model.cpp")
debug: {
    if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") {
        system.file <- function(...) {
            ans <- base::system.file(...)
            chartr("\\", "/", shortPathName(ans))
        }
    }
    if (tracesweep) 
        libtmb <- FALSE
    debug <- length(grep("-O0", flags)) && length(grep("-g", 
        flags))
    fpath <- system.file(paste0("libs", Sys.getenv("R_ARCH")), 
        package = "TMB")
    f <- paste0(fpath, "/libTMB", if (openmp) 
        "omp"
    else if (debug) 
        "dbg", ".cpp")
    libtmb <- libtmb && file.exists(f)
    if (libtmb) 
        file <- c(file, f)
    oldmvuser <- mvuser <- Sys.getenv("R_MAKEVARS_USER", 
        NA)
    if (is.na(oldmvuser)) {
        on.exit(Sys.unsetenv("R_MAKEVARS_USER"))
    }
    else {
        on.exit(Sys.setenv(R_MAKEVARS_USER = oldmvuser))
    }
    if (is.na(mvuser) && file.exists(f <- path.expand("~/.R/Makevars"))) 
        mvuser <- f
    if (!is.na(mvuser)) {
        cat("Note: Using Makevars in", mvuser, "\n")
    }
    makevars <- function(...) {
        file <- tempfile()
        args <- unlist(list(...))
        txt <- paste(names(args), args, sep = "=")
        if (!is.na(mvuser)) {
            if (file.exists(mvuser)) {
                txt <- c(readLines(mvuser), txt)
            }
        }
        writeLines(txt, file)
        Sys.setenv(R_MAKEVARS_USER = file)
        file
    }
    libname <- sub("\\.[^\\.]*$", "", basename(file[1]))
    if (safeunload) {
        valid <- c(letters[1:26], LETTERS[1:26], 0:9, "_")
        invalid <- setdiff(unique(strsplit(libname, "")[[1]]), 
            valid)
        if (length(invalid) > 0) {
            cat("Your library name has invalid characters:\n")
            print(invalid)
            cat("It is recommended to replace invalid characters by underscore.\n")
            cat("Alternatively compile with safeunload=FALSE (not recommended).\n")
            stop()
        }
    }
    if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") {
        tr <- try(dyn.unload(dynlib(libname)), silent = TRUE)
        if (!is(tr, "try-error")) 
            cat("Note: Library", paste0("'", dynlib(libname), 
                "'"), "was unloaded.\n")
    }
    useRcppEigen <- !file.exists(system.file("include/Eigen", 
        package = "TMB"))
    useContrib <- file.exists(system.file("include/contrib", 
        package = "TMB"))
    ppflags <- paste(paste0("-I", system.file("include", 
        package = "TMB")), paste0("-I", system.file("include", 
        package = "RcppEigen"))[useRcppEigen], paste0("-I", 
        system.file("include/contrib", package = "TMB"))[useContrib], 
        "-DTMB_SAFEBOUNDS"[safebounds], paste0("-DLIB_UNLOAD=R_unload_", 
            libname)[safeunload], "-DWITH_LIBTMB"[libtmb], 
        paste0("-DTMB_LIB_INIT=R_init_", libname)[libinit], 
        "-DCPPAD_FORWARD0SWEEP_TRACE"[tracesweep])
    mvfile <- makevars(PKG_CPPFLAGS = ppflags, PKG_LIBS = paste("$(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)"[openmp]), 
        PKG_CXXFLAGS = "$(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)"[openmp], 
        CXXFLAGS = flags[flags != ""], ...)
    on.exit(file.remove(mvfile), add = TRUE)
    status <- .shlib_internal(file)
    if (status != 0) 
        stop("Compilation failed")
    status
}
Browse[2]> c
Error in compile("hierarchical_earnings_model.cpp") : Compilation failed
```

Ideally the code should compile and then I could load the model using dyn.load  before I start using the BLS data to start testing on a random sample of schools.

What should I be looking for in the debug code so I can fix this compile error?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I was able to solve this by installing `RTools` and then re-installing R 3.6.0. I then installed the re-installed the required packages one by one, starting with TMB and required dependencies.